# Enum deserialization for none .NET application consuming WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

So my question is pretty simple- I have a WCF contract with a certain DataContract the includes an enum. My goal is:
1. For .Net application to desrialize this DataMember as the suitable enum
2. for none .NET application to desrialize this DataMember as int

Is there any chance that this is the default behaviour? If not how do I accomplish this goal?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you serialising your data? Enum in XML will be an XML enum type but most JSON serialisers will serialise enums as ints (and back again).

Comment: The client applications control how they deserialize the types defined in an XSD. An enumeration *is* a valid XSD type, so non-.NET types shouldn't have issues with understanding the XSD. First make sure that your non-.NET clients *do* have a problem with enums before trying to juggle ints and enums

Answer (score 0):

in .net you can cast int to your enum and viceversa, while having your int as int for the others

Comment: Is _none_ the same as NULL or is it the same as not specifying a value? WCF uses both `minoccurs="0"`, which means no value was provided, and `nillable="true"`, which means that a NULL value was provided. They are semantically different. You could also add a `NONE` member the the `enum`.

Comment: in .net you can use nullable types such as int?

Comment: @KeithPayne you confuse WCF with the XSD that defines the DTOs. In the XSD `minoccurs` means a property is optional, not that it wasn't provided. `nillable` means it can have a NULL value but doesn't say *anything* about whether it's optional or not.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I simplified things a bit. Plus, I didn't say that a nillable element is optional. Read closer ;)

Comment: Yes, you can use nullable types. The thing that makes a difference is which tool you are using to generate your xsd, which is the contract that tells the consumer of your service what the request and response xml will look like. There is some subtlety in contract generation, but if you are staying within .NET land for both the WCF service and consumer, then you don't have to worry too much about the subtlety.